# It's there any easy way to implement GUI animation with unity GUI?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used NGUI (free edition) in unity 4.x for GUI design. Now unity has its own GUI in 5.x. Is there any easy way to implement GUI animation with unity GUI?

For example, in NGUI,

- I can easily move, rotate or scale a GUI element or make some fade-in and fade-out effects.
- I can trigger the animation with buttons or hotkeys.
- I can easily set the function to run when the animation finish.

How can I implement these with unity GUI?

Comment: Try adding a Animator Controller onto the GUI, then animate it in the Unity animation window - From there you can make parameters in the Controller that activates in a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can animate GUI objects like every other object in Unity. Just attach an Animator  and a Controller, add a parameter, and make an animation in the Animation window in unity. On button press can be done in a script, if you want keyboard input. Or with a function call - to a script - if you mean a GUI button.

Animation window can be found in Windows -> Animation

Ill add an example if needed.

An example of the controller: 
[image]

Keypoints: The Trigger parameter, as the condition in the transistion into the animation state.

This makes it possible to add this line into the code:

```
anim.SetTrigger("Fire");
```

To play the animation.

Animation window:
[image]

Last but not least, ill add a video guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeZkctmoBPw If that one wasnt good enough, one can always click around.

Comment: I'm trying it in that way. It will be better if you can put an example. Thanks very much.

Answer (score -2):

Unity GUI works in a different way to most GUIs. Instead of setting up a button which then remains there until ether you tear it down or user interacts with it, on every frame it asks you to draw the GUI objects.

So animation is inherent. If you want a button to flash, simply draw it in a different colour every ten frames or so. If you want it to move, update it's x, y co-ordinates.

Comment: That is not the GUI in 5.x, the 5.x GUI has a button that remains there till you tear it down.